# How do I get event handler to keep track of how many times the user clicked it?

Tags: java, button, javafx, counter

I am a little confused as to what I am doing wrong here. The user gets 3 rolls and I am trying to use a counter to determine how many times they have clicked the JavaFX button. When I initialize the diceRollCounter before the event handler I get an error. and if I initialize the diceRollCounter within the event handler, I get the diceRollCounter resetting back to zero every time the button is clicked, which defeats its purpose.

```
int diceRollCounter = 0;

rollDice.setOnAction(e-> {
    if (diceRollCounter < 3) {
        cup.shakeCup();
        diceRollCounter++;
    } else if (diceRollCounter > 3) {
        Text noMoreRolls = new Text();
        noMoreRolls.setText("You are out of rolls for this round");
        noMoreRolls.setX(355);
        noMoreRolls.setY(525);
        root.getChildren().add(noMoreRolls);
    }
});
```

Comment: Make `diceRollCounter` a member of the class rather than a local variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't change a local variable with an event. Try using this:

```
rollDice.setOnAction(new EventHandler<>() {
    int diceRollCounter = 0;

    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        if (diceRollCounter < 3) {
            cup.shakeCup();
            diceRollCounter++;
        } else if (diceRollCounter > 3) {
            Text noMoreRolls = new Text();
            noMoreRolls.setText("You are out of rolls for this round");
            noMoreRolls.setX(355);
            noMoreRolls.setY(525);
            root.getChildren().add(noMoreRolls);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is an [article about the issue you encountered](https://dzone.com/articles/modifying-variable-inside-lambda).

An explanation about [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) (where I wrote `new EventHandler<>() {...}`).

Comment: Note that if you make `diceRollCounter` an instance variable in the surrounding class (instead of a local variable as in the OP), you can still use a lambda expression instead of the anonymous inner class.

Comment: I didn't want to do it with instance variable of the surrounding class because then you can run this code only once per instance. (or once per class if its static)

Comment: _because then you can run this code only once per instance_ and the handler resides on a ... instance button ;) Or more directly: not a really good argument. Using an instance variable (as @James_D and also @Abra) already suggested is on the way to a reasonable solution - better would be to have a real "game model" which carries to counter (and api to access it) and let the handler update that and query the model on what is allowed :) A handler is not the place to decide about business/game logic.

Comment: You are right, there is another reason I wrote it like that, and its because its more easier to explain: just copy and paste